How to read the specific memory address value from the hex file with the batch file?
I want one memory address value from the hex file and I want to compare it to the value I know, and wanted to know whether the value is matching.
And I have tried comparing one memory address with the expected value but i feel there's something wrong with the script that I could not able to get the proper output and print the actual value--
@echo off
    
REM Set the path to the hex file
set HEX_FILE="hex.hex"

REM Specify the memory address to check (in decimal)
set ADDRESS=A400

REM Specify the expected value in hexadecimal format
set EXPECTED_VALUE= 20A0E3EB

REM Convert the address to hexadecimal
set /a "ADDRESS_HEX=%ADDRESS%"

REM Read the value at the specified address from the hex file
for /f "tokens=2 delims=: " %%a in ('certutil -f -dump %HEX_FILE% ^| findstr /b /c:"%ADDRESS_HEX%:"') do (
    set VALUE=%%a
)

REM Remove leading spaces from the value
set "VALUE=%VALUE:=%"

REM Compare the actual value with the expected value
if "%VALUE%"=="%EXPECTED_VALUE%" (
    echo The value at address %ADDRESS% in file %HEX_FILE% is correct: %VALUE%
) else (
    echo The value at address %ADDRESS% in file %HEX_FILE% is incorrect. Expected: %EXPECTED_VALUE%, Actual: %VALUE%
)
    
pause


To highlight code, select the code and press the {} button

Tips/observations:
Always use a setlocal flavour to avoid environment clutter. Normally, a setlocal line should follow @echo off
Use set "var=value" for setting string values - this avoids problems caused by trailing spaces. Don't assign " or a terminal backslash or Space. Build pathnames from the elements - counterintuitively, it is likely to make the process easier. If the syntax set var="value" is used, then the quotes become part of the value assigned.
Hence,
set "HEX_FILE=hex.hex"

and
…certutil -f -dump "%HEX_FILE%" …

ADDRESS=A400 - the value is in hex, not decimal as the previous line comment remarks.
EXPECTED_VALUE= 20A0E3EB - the space is included in the value assigned.
set /a "ADDRESS_HEX=%ADDRESS%" - in your posted code, address is already in hex. You would need to convert to hex if it was decimal, which would involve building a string using a loop to provide the appropriate nybbles. Note that batch decimals are limited to 31 bits; you appear to want to process 32.
set "VALUE=%VALUE:=%" is incorrect; set "VALUE=%VALUE: =%" would remove all spaces (the string between : and =) from the variable.
if "%VALUE%"=="%EXPECTED_VALUE%" ( : You are attempting to remove spaces from VALUE but as noted previously, EXPECTED_VALUE contains a leading space, so this comparison will always be resolved as FALSE.

I can not proceed with the current edits, if i edit the script even then it is not able to compare the value,
It would be better if you provide the script.
